# Building OpenLDAP from sources and missing BerkelyDB

Tags: redhat, berkeley-db, openldap

I'm building OpenLDAP on a RHEL 5; I used instructions found at http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/113607.

All went well, until running './configure' for OpenLDAP - the following error was recorded:

```
*<earlier output snipped>*
checking for gethostbyaddr_r... yes
checking number of arguments of ctime_r... 2
checking number of arguments of gethostbyname_r... 6
checking number of arguments of gethostbyaddr_r... 8
checking db.h usability... yes
checking db.h presence... yes
checking for db.h... yes
checking for Berkeley DB major version in db.h... 5
checking for Berkeley DB minor version in db.h... 1
checking if Berkeley DB version supported by BDB/HDB backends... yes
**checking for Berkeley DB link (default)... no
configure: error: BDB/HDB: BerkeleyDB not available**
```

I have Googled like a maniac but have been unsuccessful to find a resolution - any tips on areas to explore?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry - the terminal output seems to wrap around. I' not sure why. Hope the output is still legible. Thank you for all help.

Comment: I think you should reconsider your accepted answer. Naveen provided one consistent with Stack Overflow (and not Super User).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

do `yum install db4-devel`

(or just install the prepackaged openldap, `yum install openldap-servers openldap-clients`

Comment: I used `yum install openldap-servers` and ran into problems with Mozilla NSS.  More details can be found [here](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201202/msg00364.html).  This is why I build OpenLDAP from scratch.

Comment: I'm catching an error that BDB is tool old for the version of OpenLDAP being built. Is there a way to disable BerkleyDB?

Answer (score 16):

Seems you are using tarball installation, first you should install Berkeley DB. You can find it from oracle website at [Oracle Berkeley DB Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html). Compile and install it.

```
cd db-4.7.25.NC
. ./dist/configure
make
make install
cd /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/
```

This will install BerkeleyDB. Now you need to provide the location to successfully compile OpenLDAP.

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/lib -Wl,-R,/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags"
# Build OpenLDAP
...
```

If you don't set `RPATH` then you should add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to /etc/profile.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.7/lib"
```

After this compile OpenLDAP, let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Can I safely add CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS to /etc/profile? Otherwise, after adding LD_LIBRARY_PATH and restarting the prompt, the two previous variables will be lost.

Comment: *＋1* for providing instructions to build and install the library from sources.

Answer (score 8):

For CentOS 7, do `yum install libdb-devel`. libdb4-devel did not work for me.

Comment: Yes. db4-devel is CentOS <= 6

Answer (score 6):

debian try:

> aptitude install libdb5.1 libdb5.1-dev libdb5.1-dbg

Answer (score 3):

apt-get install libdb-dev worked for me in Ubuntu Server.