# OpenLdap exptects different version of Bekerley DB

Tags: ldap, openldap, berkeley-db, centos7

I try to install the last version of OpenLdap on my Centos 7.1 64 bit through:
`yum -y install openldap openldap-clients openldap-servers`

Then when I try the test:

```
slaptest -uf slapd.conf.temp
```

I always get the same error:

```
55a7fdc5 bdb_back_initialize: BDB library version mismatch: expected Berkeley DB 5.3.28: (September  9, 2013), got Berkeley DB 5.3.21: (May 11, 2012)
55a7fdc5 backend_init: initialized for type "bdb"
slaptest: slap_init failed!
```

Have I to install last version of Berkeley DB manually and with separately procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the /build_unix/.libs folder as well.

A similar issue I ran into while running "./configure" for openldap was resolved by setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH properly.

Reference:
[Berkeley DB mismatch error while configuring LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010989/berkeley-db-mismatch-error-while-configuring-ldap)

Comment: Hi Sundeep, you are right. Only setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH the slaptest and the starting of the LDAP properly work. Anyway I've another issue in this situation. The CentOS server doesn't work properly: the command `yum update` gives me back this error  `db5 error(-30969) from dbenv->open: BDB0091 DB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch
error: cannot open Packages index using db5 -  (-30969)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm`